# How to send text messages in Jitsi?

Tags: chat, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I'm developing a standard video call application using Jitsi; I want an additional feature to let the other party know something lik "I'll be late a few minutes"
Jitsi has a built-in text chatting; but I don't know how it can be used outside the Jitsi call.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can develop with "external_api.js". when current user joined the video jitsi triggers

> participantJoined - event notifications about new participants who
>   join the room. The listener will receive an object with the following
>   structure:

```
api.on(‘participantJoined’, (object) => join(object.id));
```

[resource](https://community.jitsi.org/t/how-to-get-the-participantid/24437)

method will be triggered for each participant. Collect and store the participant "id"'s from there. Then use

> sendEndpointTextMessage - Sends a text message to another participant
>   through the datachannels.

```
api.executeCommand('sendEndpointTextMessage', 'receiverParticipantId', 'text');
```

[resource2](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-iframe)

this method for sending messages for each participant.

2. You can develop with "lib-jitsi-meet"([lib-jitsi-meet](https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet)) library and then you can use  "sendTextMessage(text)" function.

Comment: Using the "external_api.js", the command does not work properly for me. It get's sent (log in the console: [modules/API/API.js] <send-endpoint-text-message>:  Send endpoint message command received), but no message arrives anywhere.

I've been using this basic example and sent the following command via the browser's console: "api.executeCommand('sendEndpointTextMessage', '9c4678ff', 'lorem ipsum')"; I got the participant ID as you described in your post. I also tried to leave the second argument empty ('') as suggested here. Still no message anywhere. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would like to achieve exactly the same thing. Need to give notification to all participants just like in a way when it gives notification when someone raise a hand. No luck yet.